# Retrofit 2 send object with POST

Tags: android, retrofit2

i m new about Retrofit Library and i want know what s the better why to send an object with post method of retrofit.

Here is it some code.

My Class:

```
public class ExampleClass implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;


    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    public ExampleClass(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
    }

}
```

My interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("getclass/")
    Call<ExampleClass> getExampleClass(@Body ExampleClass exampleClass);
}
```

My call with retrofit:

```
......
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ExampleClass> call = apiService.getExampleClass(exampleClass);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ExampleClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ExampleClass> call, Response<ExampleClass> response) {

                int statusCode = response.code();

                Log.i(TAG, "Status Code: " + statusCode);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ExampleClass> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + t.toString());
            }

        });
```

But every time it return me status code 500.

Can someone give me an idea for send an object with retrofit?

Comment: please add the stack trace

Comment: please add your adb logs also.

Comment: did you add Gson or Jackson converter to your retrofit instance?

Comment: i also add Gson converter to my retrofit instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send it with help of @FormUrlEncoded for example :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("getclass/")
Call<ExampleClass> getExampleClass(@Field("id") int id, @Field("name") String name);
```

but I think your way is easiest and right one.

If you are not lazy you can find all about retrofit [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

Answer (score 1):

500 Internal Server Error

The 500 status code, or Internal Server Error, means that server cannot process the request for an unknown reason. Sometimes this code will appear when more specific 5xx errors are more appropriate.

This most common cause for this error is server misconfiguration (e.g. a malformed .htaccess file) or missing packages (e.g. trying to execute a PHP file without PHP installed properly).

You can review it.Itis  working fine for me

Api InterFace class

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/billingrest/save")
        Call<LoginError> sendProductList(@Body SaveBill saveBill);

}
```

SaveBill model

```
package com.example.dev.billingsoftware.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dev on 4/8/17.
 */
public class SaveBill {

    @SerializedName("customer_name")
    @Expose
    private String customerName;
    @SerializedName("customer_id")
    @Expose
    private String customerId;
    @SerializedName("bill_number")
    @Expose
    private String billNumber;
    @SerializedName("mobile_number")
    @Expose
    private String mobileNumber;
    @SerializedName("bill_date")
    @Expose
    private String billDate;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private String count;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<BillData> data = null;

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getBillNumber() {
        return billNumber;
    }

    public void setBillNumber(String billNumber) {
        this.billNumber = billNumber;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getBillDate() {
        return billDate;
    }

    public void setBillDate(String billDate) {
        this.billDate = billDate;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<BillData> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<BillData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your API server working correctly?

   [HTTP status 500 means internal server error](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Test your API server first with a reliable client. Take a look at the error logs on the server and make sure which side causes the problem.
2. Did you add Gson or Jackson converter to your retrofit instance?

   If your server is clear, then the client, your app has a problem. A malformed request body might have caused the server error.

   Did you add a Gson (or Jackson) converter? Your `@Headers` annotation doesn't automatically convert your object into json.  If your server expects json for request, you are not sending 'object', but a string of json representation of the object. Implementing `Serializable` interface is unnecessary. Gson converter will automatically convert arbitrary object into json if you add it, or you have to use `RequestBody`.

   From [Retrofit github page (REQUEST BODY section)](https://square.github.io/retrofit/):

   > If no converter is added, only `RequestBody` can be used.